# Excel IF statement conditional cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a section heading so that when items are ticked off by putting a 1 in each subsection they turn green. Once all subsections are tick off the main heading will then be marked green.

```
=IF((SUM(A7:A14)/8)<>1,"0","1")
```

I think my issue is the "0" or "1" being returned in a character rather than an integer since Excel is auto alinging to the left like it does with characters.

My conditional cell is  0< green <1 red

Comment: You don't need to put numbers in quotes: `=IF((SUM(A7:A14)/8)<>1,0,1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Removing the quotes solved this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with  cybernetic.nomad, you could not need to put numbers in quotes. The conditional formatting rules of the main heading could be: `=if((sum(A7:A14)/8)<>1,true)`, and the format is red; `=if((sum(A7:A14)/8)=1,true)`, and the format is green. The following picture is the display effect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll certainly have a look at that method of doing conditional formatting.